# Когда пишется "оторопевшими", а когда "оторопелыми"?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Например, здесь: "людьми, оторопелыми перед окружающим"? Правильно ли употреблено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словарь позволяет использовать обе формы: оторопелый (прил.) и оторопевший (прич.), но управление возможно только для  Р.п. с предлогом ОТ:

ОТОРОПЕТЬ,  Разг. Прийти в сильное замешательство, растеряться от чего-л. О. от неожиданности, от страха.

ОТОРОПЕЛЫЙ,  Разг. Пришедший в сильное замешательство, растерявшийся. О. собеседник. О. от радости ребёнок. Синонимы: опешивший, потерявшийся, растерявшийся, остолбеневший, остолбенелый, оробелый,  растерянный, потерянный,  остолбенелый.

Реально в большинстве случаев зависимые слова отсутствуют, при этом "оторопевший" используется чаще:

ПРИМЕРЫ

"Из джипа, опасливо крестясь, выглядывал его совершенно оторопевший хозяин".

"Оторопелый, пораженный пророческим тоном предостережений, я впадаю в недоумение и инстинктивно останавливаю свой бег".

"Руки ее опустились; оторопелый, растерянный взгляд блуждал без цели".

"...закричал просто оторопевший от испуга Вейссе, ― берегитесь, ― вас хотят женить!